# Type Mismatch Error when setting variable to Cell Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA so please excuse any less than concise coding. I'm trying to make a macro that searches a range for a specific string of text and then searches a different workbook for a matching string. I'm getting a type mismatch error in my code and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code I have so far, changing some variable names that might give away my company:

```vb
Sub LookForNewVariable()
    Dim CheckCell As Range
    Dim CheckRange As Range
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim NewVariable As Long

    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set CheckRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    
    For Each CheckCell In CheckRange
        c = c + 1
        If CheckCell.Value Like "*/XXXXXX" Then
            NewVariable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A" & c).Value  **<----**
            Workbooks("Other Workbook").Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("B1:B98").Find NewVariable
        End If
    Next CheckCell
End Sub
```

The type mismatch error is on the line with the bolded arrow. What I was hoping would happen is that this macro would search each cell in `CheckRange` for the text `"/XXXXXX"` and then set `NewVariable` equal to that cells value. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `What I was hoping would happen is that this macro would search each cell in CheckRange for the text "/XXXXXX" and then set NewVariable equal to that cells value` - and that's exactly what happens, you are saving a string in the form of `"*/XXXXXX"` from that cell in a variable of type `Long`. Hence the type mismatch, because a `"*/XXXXXX"` is not a `Long`.